Не работает голосование за комментарии из очередей проверок
Если нажать на стрелочку вверх напротив комментария из очереди проверок, страница прокручивается вниз и голос не ставится:


Uncaught TypeError: t.state is null ошибка в консоли браузера при попытке проголосовать. Но если очень хочется, обновите страницу и проголосуйте, сработает. Этот баг лучше на MSE отнести.

Так же во время проверки нельзя   удалить свой отзыв или поправить , раньше так не было пару дней как стало, но правильно, что если обновить страницу , то работает... Видимо что-то обновляют...

Тоже заметил. И это, между прочим, бывает не всегда. Изредка прокатывает.

@aepot, отнёс: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/399295
